# How to keep optional logging SQL Connection from blocking when server is down

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq

We have a couple database servers in our production application -- one for application data and one for logging.

The other day, the logging server went down (ops issue) and since we're using it to log view data (e.g., who viewed which object in the application), it brought down our application.  We caught it in 15 mins or so, but I'd very much like to avoid this in the future.

What's the best practice to allow "optional" connections (like background loggers) to not block the main production application?

The application is C# ASP.NET MVC 4; the servers are SQL Server 2008.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Is it running on the main thread?

Comment: Try connecting on a background thread and returning the connection if successful.  Also consider a sane connection timeout regardless.

Comment: John, yes it's running on the main thread.  If I create a background thread, might there be a chance of race conditions?

Comment: I'd be looking for some kind of queuing system (e.g. MSMQ or Service Broker) that I could just throw messages into and know that (eventually) they'll be dequeued and processed.